# How do I make persistent changes with nmcli in non interactive mode?

Tags: networkmanager

What is the correct way of making nmcli commands persistent?

For example: `nmcli device modify eth0 ipv4.method auto` works but if I reboot the machine this is lost.

I know about interactive `nmcli> save` but I do not want to use interactive mode and I was not able to find the param neded to save these.

What is the unattended version to perform this manual operations?

```
nmcli c e eth0
set  ipv4.method auto
set  ipv6.method auto
set  802-3-ethernet.mtu 9000
save persistent
quit
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorin,

if you are rebooting and finding the network connection not coming up - it could be the case that you need to set auto-connect to true.

```
nmcli con mod <connection-name> connection.autoconnect true
```

Network Manager on Centos 9 Stream places entries in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections and not /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts, so if you're got a recent version of Linux, don't take network-scripts being empty as an indication that Network Manager hasn't persisted your configuration - it may be that the configuration is persistent but simply not auto-connecting at boot or at any time.

Good luck.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be the äquivalent non-interactive version:

```
nmcli c m eth0 ipv4.method auto ipv6.method auto 802-3-ethernet.mtu 9000
```

`"save yes"` is the default, so you can omit it here